# Can't seem to edit page title in og/users/%/add_user

Tags: 7, routes, organic-groups

In our what should be titled "Add Users", both `H1` and `title` both contain the value "Home". I have even tried to overide with another module's `hook_menu_alter`.

```
function hook_menu_alter(&$items) { 
   $items['og/users/%node/add_user']['#title'] = t('test');
}
```

Page.tpl.php is untouched:

```
<?php if ($title && !$is_front): ?>
   <h1 class="title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any idea of other areas I should try?

[image]

Comment: What have you got set as your site home page?  And do you have any custom modules?  It looks like it is being overwritten by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me in this particular situation, but I'd be open to mark another answer correct if anyone had a better option inside of a `hook_form_alter()`.

```
// Force Title on the Add Users OG form. 
if ($form['#id'] == 'og-add-users') {
    drupal_set_title('Add Users');
}
```